# How to get a build of Neovim with python3 support for windows?

Tags: python, vim, neovim

I'm having a hard time adding python3 support to my neovim install on my windows machine.  I've done the following:

- Installed the official 64 bit windows build of neovim
- Installed python 3.5 (64 bit)
- Ran `pip install neovim`
- Set `g:python3_host_prog` to the path of my python3 exe in my init.vim.

Is there any step I'm missing?

I also noticed that when I run `call health#provider#check()` it prints out this:

[image]

But the python version there is 3.3+ and I have already run `pip3 install neovim` so not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Using the master build from AppVeyor (now linked on the wiki), `:CheckHealth` should work now, as well as `:python3` (after the steps you've taken), on Windows. Still some other work to be done to get to a stable Windows release.

Comment: Yep it's working now.  Thanks!  Keep up the great work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the master build from AppVeyor (now linked on the wiki), `:CheckHealth` should work now, as well as `:python3` (after the steps you've taken), on Windows. Still some other work to be done to get to a stable Windows release.
                    – Justin M. Keyes

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to run:

```
sudo pacman -S python-pip  # I use archlinux
sudo pip install neovim
```